# how to correctly compute anova/F-test in R

Tags: r, regression, anova

Assume that we have a model L1 nested into model L2, i.e. L2 is the bigger model (more complex). How do I compute the anova/F-test in R?

Do I write the small model first or the large model in anova()?

anova(L1, L2) or anova(L2, L1)?

Comment: The first, anova(L1, L2), is the correct one, the 2nd will give you a negative sum of squares.